# Mysql2 gem not working with UTF8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8, mysql2

I've switched my Rails app from the Mysql gem to Mysql2, but now UTF8 fields aren't working; specifically, the character á is coming out as Ã¡.  The character appears correctly in the MySQL console, when using PHP, and when using the Mysql gem.  I have set `encoding: utf8` in my `database.yml` file.

**Potentially helpful**

When I inspect it character-for-character in the console, I see that á is "\303\241" (using the Mysql gem) but Ã¡ is "\303\203\302\241" (using the Mysql2 gem).

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using?

Comment: Just switched to Rails 3.0.4, was previously on 2.8.7.

Comment: I have the same issue with Chinese characters.

Comment: I have the same issue with Khmer Unicode characters. Previously I used mysql gem and it work fine on my Rails2.3.8 and now I upgrade my project to rails 3 and use mysql2 gem. I found UTF8 problem with this gem.