# Smartquotes displayed fine in Rails 2, now a problem in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, utf-8, ascii, upgrade

My Rails app is working from a mysql database, and when I switched from Rails 2.8, Ruby 1.8 and the mysql gem over to Rails 3.0.7, Ruby 1.9.2 and the mysql2 gem, all of a sudden my pages are rendering with smartquotes (curly quotes) and em-dashes, etc., all looking like gibberish.

I'm assuming this has something to do with UTF-8, but I don't know how to pinpoint it.

Here's what I do know:

(1) `config/database.yml` has the following:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
```

(2) `config/application.rb` has the following:

```
config.encoding = "utf-8"
```

Don't know where to go from there.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920351/mysql2-gem-rails-3-0-3-and-incompatible-character-encodings-errors https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/124 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5084975/mysql2-gem-not-working-with-utf8 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4281194/rails-3-mysql-mysql2-misinterpreting-some-retrieved-strings-as-ascii-8bit

Answer (score 0):

You can narrow it down to the db vs the view by doing two things:

1. rails console # in your terminal in the project directory, then test that your ActiveRecord objects have the correct data.
2. ViewSource in your browser to see if the generated source is putting in the correct characters.

---

Later:

This is probably a duplicate of: [mysql2 gem, Rails 3.0.3 and "incompatible character encodings" errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920351/mysql2-gem-rails-3-0-3-and-incompatible-character-encodings-errors)  https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues/124

And maybe even the monkeypatch here: http://www.rorra.com.ar/2010/07/30/rails-3-mysql-and-utf-8/

Comment: I've looked into it on ActiveRecord: at least in my terminal it still looks weird.  e.g., `â€œ` instead of a curly quote.

It's possible that this has to do with the way I dumped and imported the database into my new environment.  (If so, is there a conversion tool?)  However, even my live production site, which is running Rails 2 and has the curly quotes displaying correctly, shows the gibberish if I use phpMyAdmin to look at the database.  So it's hard for me to know where the problem is exactly.  What do you advise?